# Bounding a pesky infinite series of logs

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is a small side problem that came up during some research. My aim is simply to hopefully show that the following series is absolutely convergent. Note that I don't need what it converges to, I just want to bound it. The series is

$\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{2} \left |\log \left(1 - \frac{|A|}{(B+j)^2 + C} \right) \right|$

where $B \ge 0$ and $C> 0$ and $C>|A|$. This website, http://pi.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/InfProd/InfProd.html#SeriesxofxLogarithms, has the identity

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \log \left(1 - \frac{z^2}{k^2 + a^2}\right) = \log\left( \frac{a \sin(\pi \sqrt{a^2+z^2})}{\sinh[a\pi]\sqrt{z^2 - a^2}} \right)$

which seems like it would do the trick but I don't know how that was arrived at and I haven't been able to turn anything up by searching.

My own approach was to look at this as an infinite product as

$\frac{1}{2} \left |\log \left(\prod_{j=-\infty}^\infty 1 - \frac{|A|}{(B+j)^2 + C} \right) \right|$

and try and use Euler's infinite product representation for Sine but I ran into trouble at the end because the resulting product could be negative which would be rather bad as an argument for log. In particular to use the identity I wanted to make $1 - \frac{|A|}{(B+j)^2+C}$ look like (bounded by) $1 - \frac{x^2}{j^2}$ but the only way I could see to do that was such that it could be that x is such that $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ could be negative and hence the potential problem. Can anybody suggest a way to bound it?

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is sufficient to show $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left|\log \left(1 - \frac{|A|}{(B+j)^2 + C} \right) \right|$ converges (the other side, and the $j=0$, are respectively similar and easily taken care of). Start by observing that
$$
 \frac{|A|}{(B+j)^2 + C} \xrightarrow[j\to\infty]{} 0
$$
so that 
$$
\left|\log \left(1 - \frac{|A|}{(B+j)^2 + C} \right) \right| \operatorname*{\sim}_{j\to\infty} \frac{|A|}{(B+j)^2 + C} \operatorname*{\sim}_{j\to\infty} \frac{|A|}{j^2}
$$
By comparison ([theorems of comparisons for non-negative series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)), the series $\sum_j \left|\log \left(1 - \frac{|A|}{(B+j)^2 + C} \right) \right| $  has same nature as the series $\sum_j\frac{|A|}{j^2}$, which is convergent.

Comment: By my calculation $\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty \frac{\log(1-\frac{|A|}{(B+j)^2+C)} /(|A|/j^2)$ goes to 0? Where doesn't the constant need to be nonzero for the comparison of non-negative series?

Comment: The constant could be $0$ for the comparison (it would work), but here unless I'm mistaken it does to one: $\lvert \log(1-x)\rvert\sim \lvert x\rvert$ when $x\to0$.

Comment: I agree that $\frac{log(1-x)}{x} \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. But the original I think has different behavior with x as something like $K/j^2$ as j goes to infinity. When I evaluated the limit via hopitals it was 0 and the wikipedia page had the constant be strictly bigger than 0. So I feel like this might not be sufficient.

Comment: After playing around with it I think your approach works if I compare it to the series $\sum \log(1-\frac{k}{j^2})$ rather than $\sum \frac{k}{j^2}$. Thanks!